# Getting error while creating AWS-OPSWORK-STACK using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Am getting this error while creating stack with terraform and below ia the code

Error: Error loading /root/terraform-stack-creation/main.tf: position 2:10: resource must be followed by exactly two strings, a type and a name

```
resource "aws_opsworks_stack" "stack" {
  name = "${var.name}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  service_role_arn = "${var.service_role_arn}"
  default_instance_profile_arn = "${var.instance_profile_arn}"
  default_os = "Amazon Linux 2018.03"
  configuration_manager_version = "11.10"
  manage_berkshelf = false
  default_root_device_type = "ebs"
  use_opsworks_security_groups = false
  vpc_id = "vpc-******************"
  default_subnet_id = "subnet-*****************"
  custom_json = "{}"
}
```

```
variable "name" {
    type = "string"
    description = "Name (Your required stack name)"
    }
variable "region" {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["us-west-1a"]
    description = "us-east-1,ap-south-1,ap-southeast-2,eu-central-1 (Give your region)"
    }
variable "service_role_arn" {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["*********************"]
    description = "Default IAM role"
    }
variable "default_instance_profile_arn"{
    type = list(string)
    default = ["*************************"]
    description = "Default IAM instance profile"
    }
variable "default_availability_zone" {
    type = "string"
    description = "Give your availabity zone"
    }
```

Comment: That error happens when you define a resource without both the type and the name (as the error implies) in double quotes after it eg `resource "type" "name"`. Your provided code, however, doesn't have that issue. Are you sure that that code has that exact error? Is the `aws_opsworks_stack` resource on line 2 of your main.tf file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The variable `name` isn't set to anything.

You'll need to either:

a) set a default for `name`

b) set the `name` variable through [environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html#environment-variables), [the command line](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html#variable-precedence), [`TF_INPUT=false` or `-input=false`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_input), or other methods

Comment: That isn't the case at all as you get a completely different error if a variable isn't set and you're using `-input=false`. If you aren't using `-input=false` then you just get prompted for the variable value.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I thought that was covered under "other methods", but i'll include a link to that as well

Comment: @StephenG  have fixed the error by adding service role arn and instance profile arn in main file itself.

Comment: @VaithiyanathanS another great way to fix it!